# Are questions about hardware requirements for Moodle acceptable here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I would like to know what kind of hardware is approximately needed for Moodle to work with 500-5000 students synchronously.

A similar question has been asked 8 years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741156/can-moodle-deal-with-more-than-100-000-users), but my gut tells me that such a question may be closed immediately today on SO.

Do you think such a question is acceptable on SO today?

Comment: I don't think that is a programming problem. Even the question you linked to isn't a programming problem. It is a tool setup / scaling issue and those tend to be too localized to be useful for any future visitors.

Comment: Note that the question you used as supporting evidence has now been closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question would be completely off-topic.

And very difficult to answer in any case, either on the site or in real life.

Not all course modules have the same requirements, and very likely a Moodle instance that is planned for up to 5000 simultaneous users will very have a ton of customization made, which will affect the hardware requirements as well.

Only the developers can get an idea of what's needed doing load testing and hoping for the best. Also, having an order of magnitude variance in expected simultaneous users will drive your requirements through the roof.

I'm afraid a project this big cannot be budgeted by asking a question to strangers, and the question would not be a good fit for the site.